# Cleanmymac has left folder actions after uninstall

Tags: macos, mac

I recently tried a trial period of the app CleanMyMac for Mac OS X.
After uninstall I see that its still left its folder actions in my finder context menus.

[image]

How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check your Library folders. The files that cause the appearance of the folder actions can be found here:

```
 ~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts
```

or

```
 ~/Library/Scripts/Contextual Menu Items.
```

Uninstalling software can be a pain sometimes, but applications such as Appzapper do their job pretty well. You can find it here [macupdate: appzapper](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20306/appzapper)

Comment: In the free software department, there is also http://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/

Answer (score 0):

CleanMyMac leaves more trash than that.  Search for "CleanMyMac" in your ~/Library folder, and delete all that shows up.